# MVC5 jQuery autocomplete plugin via Ajax for field

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have two tables `Student` `{Id,cityId...}` and `City` `{cityId,Name}`.
I want the field `city name` to autocomplete from `tblCity`, on create and edit View.

adding id :

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City.CityName, new {  id = "autoCity"  })
```

I tried `JSON`, but no responce :

```
 public ActionResult AutoComplete(String term)
        {
    var cities = from d in db.Cities
                             orderby d.CityName
                             select d;
                var search = db.Cities.Where(s => s.CityName.Contains(term)).Take(2).Select(l => new { label = l.CityName });

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
                {               
                    cities = cities.Where(s => s.CityName.Contains(term));
                }
                return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

on my View :

```
$("#autoCity").autocomplete({
        source: "/Student/AutoComplete",
        minLenght: 2
    });
```

on mu _layout I call:

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

How do I combine the Ajax here?
 What have I done wrong on My `AutoComplete` func?

**solved** by replacing:
view:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City.CityID, "City", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City.CityName,
        new
        {
            @class = "autocomplete-with-hidden",
            data_url = Url.Action("GetListForAutocomplete", "Student")
        })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CityID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityID)
            </div>
        </div>
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.autocomplete-with-hidden').autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var url = $(this.element).data('url');
                    $.getJSON(url, { term: request.term }, function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { value: item.value, id: item.id }
                        }));
                    })
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $(event.target).next('input[type=hidden]').val(ui.item.id);
                },
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.item) {
                        $(event.target).val('').next('input[type=hidden]').val('');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

control:

```
public JsonResult GetListForAutocomplete(string term)
        {
            City[] matching = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(term) ?
                db.Cities.ToArray() :
                db.Cities.Where(p => p.CityName.StartsWith(term)).ToArray();

            return Json(matching.Select(m => new
            {
                id = m.CityID,
                value = m.CityName,
                label = m.ToString()
            }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: what error you are getting in your browser console. You should use `baseURl + "/Student/AutoComplete"`. Complete URL need.

Comment: without error , just not response, "/Student/AutoComplete"="controller/action "

Comment: Put break point to Controller Actin have you reach to that action?? if not then use full path from root to for source. You are not passing `term` in your url. It can not find matched Action with `term` parameter.

Comment: Solved! I replace @Html.EditorFor to TextBoxFor and it's works.